# Reduced free group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a $d$-generated group. Then my first question is how to see free reduced group $FV(G)$ in the variety containing $G$. What I understood is: "Let $W \subset F_d$ ($d$-generated free group) be the collection of words which are laws for $G$, i.e. for every $w \in W$ image of word map $w$ on $G$ is identity. Let $F_m$ be m-generated free group and $S$ be the union of images of words $w \in W$ in $F_m$. If $FV(G)$ is the $m$-generated reduced free group then $FV(G) = \frac{F_m}{\langle S \rangle}$."

My second question is when $G$ is finite group then is it true that finitely generated  free reduced group $FV(G)$ will also be finite?  Where can I read more about free reduced group?

Thank you!

Comment: The answer to your second question is yes.  This is an old result of Birkhoff that maybe answers your first question.  If $A$ is any universal algebra the free object on $X$ in the variety generated by $A$ embeds in $A^{A^X}$ where you send $x$ to the the tuple whose $f$-coordinate is $f(x)$.  This is finite is $A$ and $X$ are. This might also answer your first question but I'm not clear exactly what you are asking.  The description as a quotient of the free group you give is correct

Comment: I think this is rather known as "*relatively* free group in the variety *generated by* $G$".

Comment: Few years ago I asked a similar question here and YCor  answered it. See https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=Free+elements+in+the+variety+generated+by+S_3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give a more detailed answer.  My comment above about your first question was wrong because I read it too quickly and didn't catch the difference between $m$ and $d$.  Your description of the free object in question 1 is off.

Take the cyclic group $C_n$ of order $n\geq 3$.  Then $C_n$ is $1$-generated and the laws it satisfies in one variable are all consequences of $x^n=1$.  But it also satisfies $xy=yx$, which is not a consequence of this law when $n\geq 3$.

If $A$ is a universal algebra, then the variety generated by $A$ is defined by all laws satisfied by $A$.  So you should factor the free group out by the verbal subgroup generated by all laws satisfied by $G$.

For the second question, the answer is yes as I said in the comment. If $A$ is a universal algebra, then the free object in the variety generated by $A$ on a generating set $X$ embeds in $A^{A^X}$ via the map $\psi\colon X\to A^{A^X}$ with $\psi(x)(f)=f(x)$.  This $X$ generates a relatively free object because any mapping $f\colon X\to A$ factors through $\psi$ by projecting the the $f$-coordinate and so every map from the free object on $X$ in the signature of $A$ to $A$ factors through the map induced by $\psi$.  Now it is easy to verify that $\psi(X)$ generates a relatively free algebra in the variety generated by $A$ using the description as quotients of subalgebras of direct products of copies of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The relative free group of rank $n$ corresponds directly to a set of maps from $G^n\rightarrow G$. These maps are the coset representatives of $F_n/K$ where $K$ is the group of $n$-variable laws of $G$.

If $G$ is finite, then there are only finitely many such maps and hence the relative free group itself is finite.